# How shall I write the derivative of a function $f(x)$: $f_{,x}(x)$ or $f(x)_{,x}$?

Tags: calculus

I want to write the derivative of a function $f(x)$ wrt $x$. I have two options:  $f_{,x}(x)$ and $f(x)_{,x}$. Which one is right?

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen either notation. If $f$ is a function of just one variable then $f'$ is its derivative. If you want to indicate that the derivative is with respect to a variable called "$x$" you can write
$$
\frac{d}{dx}f \quad \text{ or }\quad \frac{df}{dx} 
\quad \text{ or }\quad f'(x).
$$

Answer (score 2):

First one is the more standard notation. It makes sense since you are really having the function $f_{,x}$ and then you evaluate it at the point $x_0$. Then you get $f_{,x}(x_0)$. In your case you are then confusing $x$ and $x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

If your function is $f(x,y)$, and $x$ is a single variable (i.e. $x\in \mathbb R$) and not a vector, I'd go with the notation $f^{(1,0)}(x)$, which means one partial derivative after the first variable, and no after the second variable.

From your two options though, I'd go with $f_{,x}(x)$, as the $(x)$ is the point being substituted, so you might have long expressions in there, in which the second notation style will be confusing
$$
f_{,x}(\frac{e^{x-2/x}+4x}{3x}) \qquad \text{vs.}\qquad f(\frac{e^{x-2/x}+4x}{3x})_{,x}
$$